# FAQ for scicomp.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

Inspired by [this meta.math.stackoverflow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/107/9281) question, I thought it would be useful to start a meta discussion about the contents of the eventual [scicomp FAQ](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/faq).

As usual with a new stackexchange site, our FAQ currently only contains the standard boilerplate FAQ, talking about questions, reputation, the beta, etiquette and collaboration etc.

Hopefully this page can serve as an index of other important support questions for our community.

- Please post each proposed FAQ as a separate community wiki answer, so we can collaboratively edit the FAQ. If you add a new proposed FAQ, add a link to it in the index below.
- Alternatively, if you find a question with the [faq-proposed](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag that needs highlighting here, add it to the *Index of questions with the [faq-proposed](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag* section, below.

Useful references:

- `meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com` questions tagged with the [faq-proposed](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag.
- `meta.stackoverflow.com` questions tagged with the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=faq&sort=votes) tag.

#### Index of questions in this thread:

- [How do I add mathematical equations to my question/answer/comment?](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34/149)
- [Are homework questions on topic?](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/97/149)

#### Index of questions with the [faq-proposed](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag:

- [So, what is the elevator pitch for the site?](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/149)
- [The FAQ should include a note about clarifying your terminology](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/149)
- This Question ( [FAQ for scicomp.stackexchange](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/149) )
- [What is our policy on ambiguous tags?](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/39/149)
- [What should be our answer to "what kind of questions can I ask here?"](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/41/149)

Comment: Two questions that apply to the FAQ question what can be asked: http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1/so-what-is-the-elevator-pitch-for-the-site and http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-should-be-our-answer-to-what-kind-of-questions-can-i-ask-here.  I've added [tag:faq-proposed] to both of these.

Comment: Thanks @BrianDiggs - I've added them to the index for easy reference.

Answer (score 5):

**Q:** *Are homework questions on topic?*

**A:** *Yes, provided they meet the following guidelines:*

*1. The poster demonstrates they've thought about the assignment they're trying to solve by describing their initial approach.*

*2. The poster is looking for clarification on a specific point of confusion, rather than asking the community to solve a homework assignment.*

*3. The poster asks a question that is otherwise on topic for `scicomp.stackexchange`.*

*Think of the community as being like a teaching assistant. Teaching assistants provide guidance and answer topical question without solving homework for students.*

The text is derived from my answer to [this question on meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/what-specifically-is-off-topic-about-the-sequence-alignment-question); feel free to comment and edit for style.

Answer (score 4):

**Q**: *How do I add mathematical equations to my question/answer/comment?*

**A**: ...

There are some good proposals to answer this over at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com in this [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/117/9281) and answers to this [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/9281), but someone with more experience of MathJax would be better placed to review them.

Comment: In any event: [these](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/tex.html#supported-latex-commands) are the LaTeX commands that MathJax knows how to parse.

Comment: @J.M. - Do you (or does anyone else) fancy having a go at summarising those other answers to this same question? I made this answer CW to make it easier for someone who knows MathJax/LaTeX well (but doesn't have much rep) to replace my boilerplate answer with a better one. Thanks,

Comment: Maybe later. I'm doing a few other things at the moment; unless somebody beats me to it and writes something way better than I can ever produce, I'll take a crack at writing a tidy summary...